# Django storages: Need authenticated way of reading static files from google cloud storage

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles, python-django-storages

I am trying to read static files from GCP storage using a service account key. The problem is while most of the requests are authenticated [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/gcloud.html), some of the requests are public.

[Developer console: Networks tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2Q1o.jpg)

And because of which I am getting a broken Django admin UI.

[Broken Django admin UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7Lzu.png)

Here's my static file settings in `settings.py` file.

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
if DEPLOYED_URL:
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage"
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = "storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage"
    GS_BUCKET_NAME = env("GS_BUCKET_NAME")
    GS_CREDENTIALS = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
        json.loads(get_secret(PROJECT_NAME, "service_account_json"))
    )
    GS_DEFAULT_ACL = "projectPrivate"
```

My restrictions are I have `Fine-grained: Object-level ACLs enabled` bucket on which public access cannot be given.

PS: Since there are restrictions to the project I cannot use a public bucket. Alternate ways other than the usage of `django-storages` package are also appreciated. The only condition is reads should be authenticated and not public.

Comment: Where is this error happening? Locally or deployed? Both?

Comment: This error is happening when the app is deployed. @Hayden

Comment: See here: https://www.viget.com/articles/using-google-cloud-storage-in-your-django-project/

Comment: @Hayden Tried the link but it did not work.

Comment: Then my next question would be to ask myself if I really have to serve my static files from GCP or if I can just serve them regularly.

Comment: Thanks @Hayden went with whitenoise to host staticfiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing this, it's apparently an open [bug](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/issues/1031) related to django-storages but on AWS. But similar thing is happening on GCP on further inspection.

I have already deployed my application using [whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html) to overcome this bug and have hosted my application on GCP cloud run.